# a function calculate has been used in a true/false expression that is used as a table filter expression which is not allowed

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a to check the current month and current year value for a measure in ssas tabular model but due to type mismatch i am not able to do this. For this, i have created a measure in which i am using this dax query

```
:CurrMonthYear:=CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE("""",concatenate(year(now()),CONCATENATE(0,month(now())))),"""")       output: "201704"
```

...to calculate currentyear and currentmonth. But when i give this value in a measure like this:

```
SumOfRevisedForecast:=CALCULATE(SUM(DimRevisedForecast[RevisedForecast]),DimRevisedForecast[Approved] <>"N"  && DimRevisedForecast[Approved] <>blank(),'DimRevisedForecast'[CalendarYearMonth] =CurrMonthYear)
```

...this doesnt work. Though, giving "201704" in place of CurrMonthYear works.

Can anybody help me in this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14):

The problem is not with CurrMonthYear measure, it's with your second formula - CALCULATE function does not accept measures as criteria, only values. That's why it works when you put "201704" explicitly but fails when you use the measure.

A common solution is to wrap the criteria into FILTER function, something like:

```
CALCULATE(SUM(DimRevisedForecast[RevisedForecast]), 
          FILTER ('DimRevisedForecast',  
                  'DimRevisedForecast'[CalendarYearMonth] = [CurrMonthYear])
```

A great explanation of this issue is here:
[FILTER() – When, Why, & How to Use It](https://powerpivotpro.com/2012/06/filter-when-why-how-to-use-it/)